# Use multiple SD cards in RAID 0?

Tags: sd-card

Is there a way to use multiple SD-memory cards with the Raspberry Pi, perhaps in RAID 0 configuration?  It would be a good way to expand the available memory, reuse some of extra the cards that I have, and keep the Wattage low (compared to an external drive).

Comment: You could use a SD-card-reader and just plug it into the USB port.

Answer (score 3):

there's only one SD slot on the Raspberry Pi, so you'll need some external hardware, and as far as external hardware goes, you cannot beat a good HDD with a pack of old and faulty flash cards.

and regarding the power consumption, contemporary 2.5" HDD consumes about 0.15-0.2A on average, that's about 1/4-1/5 of what your Pi consumes, you can hardly go any lower than that using powered USB hubs and all this stuff you'll need to access your SD reader cards.

Comment: Actually **[electric power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power)** is defined in watts (W), which can be expressed with current and voltage. Eelctric power formula for DC current is: **P = I x V**. So, if we go to your example: [Rpi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6050) consume ~0.2A@12.5V_DC (**2.5W**) and external USB 2.5 " [HDD](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/500-gb-external-storage-tested,1670-13.html) consume about 1.25A@12V_DC (15W).

Comment: @TomiL your numbers are way off, there are no 12V anywhere in the Raspberry Pi. Also, I wonder where did you find 12V in the USB (5v powered) device. Use Google, it should help.

Comment: my numbers are taken from the website provided in my link(from [www.raspberrypi.org](http://www.raspberrypi.org)).The _alexeames_ was using 3x LiPoly (so this is where 12.5V is comming from!),consider 90% efficiency of switching regulator he used, we get 0.45A@5V_DC on Rpi's input power line.As we know, the external HDD *can't be directly powered* from Rpi's USB (providing only ~140mA/USB port), so also ext.power supply for ext.HDD is needed.In my case those were in 95%(of all HDDs I ever had) on 12V DC adapter.This is the thing I was trying to say:specify current AND voltage. :)

Comment: Btw, 0.2A on USB2.0 bus means only 1W of power, which is really just _average power consumption_ for portable USB HDD (not flash!) and when we consider most of the time is _idle mode_ or similar (_low energy/sleep/low spin_).
Btw, most PC/laptop 2.0 USBs are capable of providing >500mA of power as standard says! This is way we are able to run portable USB HDD on only 1 port.
And YES, I agree with you regarding comparison between _2.5" HDD_ and _old and faulty flash cards_. ;)

Comment: A typical 2.5" 5400rpm HDD will require about an amp of five vijayjay to spin up. That's five watts, and if you're not careful, I guarantee that you *will* damage that sensitive device of yours. You could stagger that spin-up with some (nice, chunky, like you might find in a camera flash) capacitors. Another option might be to power the drive externally, though there are implications regarding standard compliance if we explore the wrong avenues in that case.

Comment: The least efficient form of work that any NAND flash does is writing. It generates the most heat and wear per unit of work load, in such a significant way that warranties are void if you write more than a certain amount per day, or once a certain amount has been written. That's the failure mode, and it's the power thirst mode, too... **However**, that doesn't mean SSDs aren't suitable for applications where *much more read operations occur*, such as boot images, media and popular software. In any case, it'd astound me if you could spin up a 3.5" HDD but you couldn't operate a 2.5" SSD...

Answer (score 0):

**Software RAID**

In relevance to this [Super User answer.](https://superuser.com/a/612954)

You can get a whole lot of SD to USB adapters because there are no multi SD port readers. Then you set up raid in Linux or use [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) on the SD Cards

**4 Ports SD to SATA Adapter**

*Runs in RAID-0*

You will need to use a SATA to USB to use this.

[image]

[image]

**CF Interface**

*Runs in RAID-0*

You can get a CF to USB convertor.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**1. solution: USB style**

Is your attention only to extend program memory? Then, as @Gerben already said, buy/use USB SD-card reader. But than you don't need [RAID 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#RAID_0) configuration. It is meant to be for improving performance while using [data striping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_striping), but major drawback is fault tolerance: if one element in array dies, whole array is corrupted.

**2. solution: network style**

One solution could be to search for any (free) hosting, like ftp, http, etc. Then just copy user data to web storage. Or use your own server, like [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). You can use ethernet or USB (e.g. USB WiFi dongle, USB Bluetooth, etc.).

**3. solution: GPIO style**

There are also some GPIO pins already on the board with various protocols: [UART TTL, SPI, IIC](http://sansgridpdx.com/images/6/68/Raspberry-pi-rev-1-gpio-pin-out1.jpg). Those can be directly connected to other external devices via TTL pins.

So, *the only limitation is your imagination* ;)